# Slider "before" bar overlaps on top of thumb in HTML/CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension

I am making a web audio player with a slider control bar. I used the `<input type="slider">` tag to display the slider, and I've got it to work 90% of the way. The only issue now is that the "before" bar, implemented with ".slider:before" in CSS, overlaps on top of the thumb button (especially as you move the thumb toward the end). Here is what it looks like:

[image: current UI]

I would like to see how to make it so that the darker "before" bar hides under the thumb

### Here is my code

```js
const seekSlider = document.getElementById('slider');
    
const showRangeProgress = (rangeInput) => {
  seekSlider.style.setProperty('--seek-before-width', `${rangeInput.value}%`);
}

seekSlider.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
    showRangeProgress(e.target);
})
```

```css
input[type="range"] {
      width: 185px;
    }
    
    .slider {
      position: relative;
      margin-left: 10px;
      cursor: pointer;
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      height: 10px;
      outline: none;
      margin-top: 7px;
      margin-bottom: -3px;
      opacity: 0.7;
      transition: 0.3s;
    }
    
    .slider::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
      height: 3px;
      background: rgba(66, 64, 70, 0.15);
    }
    
    .slider::before {
      position: absolute;
      content: "";
      width: var(--seek-before-width);
      height: 3px;
      margin-top: 4px;
      background-color: rgba(203, 195, 227, 0.8);
    }
    
    .slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      width: 8px;
      height: 8px;
      background: #a8a3b3;
      border-radius: 50%;
      margin-top: -2px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="controls" class="controls">
  <input id="slider" type="range" value="0" max="100" class="slider">
  <p id="time" class="time">0:00</p>
  <p class="endtime">3:25</p>
</div>
```

Here is kind of what I would like to achieve:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `z-index:-1;` property to your  `.slider::before` class will do the job.

**Try the following snippet**

```js
const seekSlider = document.getElementById('slider');
        
const showRangeProgress = (rangeInput) => {
  seekSlider.style.setProperty('--seek-before-width', `${rangeInput.value}%`);
}

seekSlider.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
    showRangeProgress(e.target);
})
```

```css
input[type="range"] {
          width: 185px;
        }
        
        .slider {
          position: relative;
          margin: 10px;
          cursor: pointer;
          height: 9px;
          outline: none;
          opacity: 0.7;
          transition: 0.3s;
        }
        
        .slider::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
          height: 3px;
          background: rgba(66, 64, 70, 0.15);
        }
        
        .slider::before {
          position: absolute;
          content: "";
          width: var(--seek-before-width);
          height: 3px;
          margin-top: 4px;
          z-index:-1;
        }
        
        .slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
          width: 9px;
          height: 9px;
          margin-top:-6px;
          background: #a8a3b3;
          border-radius: 50%;
          background-color:grey;
        }
```

```html
<input id="slider" type="range" value="0" max="100" class="slider">
```

> **Definition and Usage**: the `z-index` property specifies the stack order of an element. An element with greater stack order is always in
> front of an element with a lower stack order.
>
> **Note:** `z-index` only works on positioned elements (`position: absolute`, `position: relative`, `position: fixed`, or `position: sticky`)
> and flex items (elements that are direct children of `display:flex`
> elements).

Comment: Thanks! Now the before bar doesn't overlap the thumb, but another problem arises: it starts disappearing when I hover over it :((

Comment: Maybe there is some css `:hover` asociated with a div that overlaps the slider. Play with the z-index and review your divs with hover effect. If you cannot fix it, send me an email if you want with a link to your project or your full code. I updated the code for firefox and chrome compatibility. Try also searching for sliders already coded.